# Play cue sheets in Android

Tags: android, audio, audio-player, flac, cue-sheet

I want to add playing cue sheets to my music app. I saw some apps like Poweramp and AndLess that can do this, but I have no idea how do they read cue files. Maybe there is some way to parse cue sheet and make a link to specific point in the flac file.
Example of cue sheet i want to play:

```
REM GENRE Rock
REM DATE 1967
REM DISCID C10C380E
REM COMMENT "ExactAudioCopy v0.99pb4"
PERFORMER "The Doors"
TITLE "The Doors [40th Anniversary Mixes]"
FILE "The Doors - The Doors [40th Anniversary Mixes].flac" WAVE
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    TITLE "Break On Through (To The Other Side)"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
  TRACK 02 AUDIO
    TITLE "Soul Kitchen"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 02:25:69
    INDEX 01 02:28:19
  TRACK 03 AUDIO
    TITLE "The Crystal Ship"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 05:59:41
    INDEX 01 06:02:17
  TRACK 04 AUDIO
    TITLE "Twentieth Century Fox"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 08:34:51
    INDEX 01 08:36:62
  TRACK 05 AUDIO
    TITLE "Alabama Song (Whisky Bar)"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 11:09:13
    INDEX 01 11:10:48
  TRACK 06 AUDIO
    TITLE "Light My Fire"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 14:25:48
    INDEX 01 14:28:26
  TRACK 07 AUDIO
    TITLE "Back Door Man"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 21:26:35
    INDEX 01 21:28:48
  TRACK 08 AUDIO
    TITLE "I Looked At You"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 25:00:15
    INDEX 01 25:02:58
  TRACK 09 AUDIO
    TITLE "End of the Night"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 27:23:52
    INDEX 01 27:27:18
  TRACK 10 AUDIO
    TITLE "Take it as it Comes"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 30:16:36
    INDEX 01 30:18:07
  TRACK 11 AUDIO
    TITLE "The End"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 32:33:42
    INDEX 01 32:37:44
  TRACK 12 AUDIO
    TITLE "Moonlight Drive (Version 1)"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 44:16:48
    INDEX 01 44:18:54
  TRACK 13 AUDIO
    TITLE "Moonlight Drive (Version 2)"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 46:59:56
    INDEX 01 47:01:04
  TRACK 14 AUDIO
    TITLE "Indian Summer (8-19-66 Vocal)"
    PERFORMER "The Doors"
    INDEX 00 49:30:46
    INDEX 01 49:32:29
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is a fairly generic question, can you be more specific as to what code you have tried and what is not working?

Comment: Hi, i was hoping to get some links or libs because i don't know how to do this.